# Convergence of expectations to $\mu$ plus convergence of variance to zero implies convergence in probability to $\mu$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $\{X_n\}$ be real valued random variables so that $EX_n\to \mu, Var[X_n]\to 0$. **Just checking if this means $X_n \to_{p} \mu$ in probability?**

So here's what I tried:

Fix $\epsilon > 0.$ Apply Markov's inequality: $P[|X_n - \mu|> \epsilon] \le \frac{E|X_n - \mu|}{\epsilon} \le \sqrt{\frac{E|X_n - \mu|^2}{\epsilon^2}}$ by Cauchy-Scwartz inequality, and then: $E|X_n - \mu|^2 = E[(X_n - EX_n)^2] + (EX_n - \mu)^2 = Var[X_n] + (EX_n - \mu)^2 \to 0 $ by assumption .

This proves $X_n \to_{p} \mu$, I hope. **Could you please just check my arguments, thanks!**

Comment: $L^1$ convergence, alone, implies probability convergence. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables
Anyway, the proof is right!

Comment: @Cuoredicervo Thanks for your comment! Do you mean by $L^1$-convergence that: $E|X_n - \mu| \to 0?$ Then yes, it's true from Markov's inequality. I guess you didn't mean $EX_n \to \mu,$ as then $X_n \sim N(0, n)$ would provide a counterexample where $EX_n = 0,$ but $X_n \to_{p} 0$ isn't true.

Comment: You are completely right, I read something else. Of course the only convergence of mean tells you nothing about the behaviour of the sequence. As you said, you could have a sequence of Normal distributions (but it would be still a nice example). So yes, in any case the second assertion, about the Variance, is actually the $L^2$ norm, so yes.